# How to get 1 instance of each StreetName for a given CityTown

Tags: sql-server

I have a many thousand record **iAddress** table. An example image is shown below. In case the image can't be seen, I've also included a textual column representation for the table on the next line.

ID | UnNo | UnType | CivNo | CivNoSuffix | StreetName | StDir | CityTown | Prov | PC | CtyId

I need a query that will return only one instance of each StreetName in alphabetical order for a given CityTown in a given County that I then bind to a dropdownlist.

I am currently using the following query which I thought was working but recently noticed that in large return sets some StreetName instances are missing from the list. Any ideas on how to improve to make the query return 100% accurate results?

```sql
SELECT * FROM iAddress WHERE CtyId=@CI AND CityTown=@CT AND ID in (Select max(ID) FROM iAddress group by StreetName) Order By StreetName
```

[image: Address table]

Comment: Do you need only the StreetName value back so that SELECT StreetNAme can be used instead of SELECT *?

Comment: I need a unique DataValueField to Bind to my dropdownlist, but the values are irrelevant as I only use the StreetName value.  Your second version worked and resolved the problem of missed StreetName values described in my question above.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as your solution resolved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the StreetName to bind to the dropdown, then perhaps

```
SELECT StreetName
FROM iAddress
WHERE CtyId = @CI AND CityTown = @CT
GROUP BY StreetName
ORDER BY StreetName
```

Otherwise, the ID you now use might be from the wrong city.  The MAX(ID) needs to be for just the town you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM iAddress 
WHERE ID in (
    Select max(ID) 
    FROM iAddress 
    WHERE CtyId = @CI AND CityTown = @CT
    group by StreetName) 
Order By StreetName
```

Answer (score 0):

**A rownumbering solution should work nicely:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StreetName ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM iAddress
    WHERE CtyId = @CI AND CityTown = @CT
) i
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY StreetName
```